# Espresso test in release

Tags: android, android-espresso

I try to run Espresso tests in release

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       ...
    }

    testBuildType "release"
}
```

and when I run

```
./gradlew assembleAndroidTest
```

This task fails

```
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForAdminReleaseAndroidTest
```

I run into this and I don't have any clue how to get rid it. Maybe someone has the right hint, how to solve it

```
R8: Missing class: org.easymock.IArgumentMatcher
R8: Missing class: org.jmock.core.Constraint
R8: Missing class: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
R8: Missing class: org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor
R8: Missing class: java.lang.ClassValue
R8: 'android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback asInterface(android.os.IBinder)' already has a mapping
R8: 'void onRelationshipValidationResult(int,android.net.Uri,boolean,android.os.Bundle)' already has a mapping
R8: 'void extraCallback(java.lang.String,android.os.Bundle)' already has a mapping
R8: 'android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsService asInterface(android.os.IBinder)' already has a mapping
R8: 'boolean validateRelationship(android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback,int,android.net.Uri,android.os.Bundle)' already has a mapping
R8: 'android.support.customtabs.IPostMessageService asInterface(android.os.IBinder)' already has a mapping
R8: 'void onPostMessage(android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback,java.lang.String,android.os.Bundle)' already has a mapping
R8: 'android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel asInterface
...
...
R8: 'retrofit2.Converter requestBodyConverter(java.lang.reflect.Type,java.lang.annotation.Annotation[],java.lang.annotation.Annotation[],retrofit2.Retrofit)' already has a mapping
R8: 'void <clinit>()' already has a mapping
R8: 'void plant(timber.log.Timber$Tree[])' already has a mapping
R8: 'void prepareLog(int,java.lang.Throwable,java.lang.String,java.lang.Object[])' already has a mapping

> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForAdminReleaseAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is most likely because your espresso tests should be sitting in the androidTest package which is not built when you are running a release variant. If you want to run espresso tests you need to be running on a debug variant.